# How to create a Maze Solver in Java using Stack, Queue and Coordinate?

Tags: java, generics, stack, queue, maze

I want to create a Maze Solver in Java using the following generic classes: Queue, Stack and Coordinate (that stores the current [x,y] coordinate). The program reads a text file containing a maze, transfering it to a matrix, and from the start position, searches for and moves to empty spaces until it finds the final position.

This is the text file:

```
   5
   8
   ########
   E      #
   ### ####
   ### ####
   ###S####
```

Because the Queue, Stack and Coordinate generic classes must be present in the program, 4 objects must be created:

-One object of the class Stack < Coordinate > called "path" and an object of the class
Stack< Queue < Coordinate > > called "possibilities", both capable of storing 40 coordinates (5 x 8 -
5 rows and 8 columns);

-One object of the class Queue called "queue" that stores 3 coordinates and queues the empty spaces or the char 'S' around the current position that are found when searching all 4 directions. (In the first search, for example, the queue would be: [(1,1), , ] As 1,1 is the first empty space found from the start position, which is then added to the queue.)

-One object of the Coordinate class called "current", which represents the current position.

5 represents the number of lines. 8 represents the number of columns. The char '#' represents a wall, an unpassable terrain. The char 'E' is the start position, the char 'S' is the exit and the empty spaces (char ' ') represents walkable spaces. So the program first transfers the maze on the text file to a matrix with the specified number of lines and columns on it (5 and 8), and then finds the char 'E', which is the start position and instantiates the "current" object, storing its coordinate on it ( (1,0) in the case).

From there, it searches all 4 directions around the current position clock-wise (up, right, down and left, in this order) and stores the coordinates of the empty spaces (or char 'S') found on the "queue" object and removes the first coordinate from the "queue", storing this coordinate on the "current" object, which represents the current position. Then, on the matrix, puts a char '*' on the position represented by the "current" object (coordinate), indicating that a step was taken. Then, stacks the object "current" on the "path" object and stacks the "queue" object on the object "possibilites". 
Then repeats those steps until it finds the exit (char 'S'), printing the matrix and closing the program.

At the end, as each position is marked with a '*', the matrix would have to look like that:
(the text file is unchanged).

```
   5
   8
   ########
   E***   #
   ###*####
   ###*####
   ###S####
```

So far, I have created the classes:

Queue:

```
public class Fila <T> {
    private Object[objfila] = null;
    private int quantidade,posinicial,posfinal;
    public void inserir(Object x) throws Exception
    {
        if(quantidade==objfila.length)
            throw new Exception("Queue is full");
        x=objfila(posfinal);
        quantidade++;
        posfinal++;
    }
    public void remover() throws Exception
    {
        if(quantidade==0){
            throw new Exception("there are no elements on the queue");
        }
        quantidade--;
        posinicial++;
    }
    public Fila(int capacidade)
    {
        this.posinicial=0;
        this.posfinal=0;
        Object objfila=new Object();
    }
}
```

Stack:

```
public class Pilha <T> {
    private Object[] objpilha = null;
    private int topo;
    public void inserir(T x) throws Exception
    {
        if(topo==objpilha.length-1){
            throw new Exception("the stack is full.");
        }
        topo++;
        objpilha[topo]=x;
    }
    public void remover() throws Exception
    {
        if(topo==-1){
            throw new Exception("there are no elements to be removed.");
        }
        topo--;
    }
    public Pilha(int capacidade){
        objpilha=new Object[capacidade];
        topo=-1;
    }
}
```

And Coordinate: (I think there should be an array of x and y that stores coordinates)

```
public class Coordenadas <T>{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```

What I am having problems with is the creation of those objects and inserting them into other objects, as in storing found coordinates on the "queue" and stacking the "current" object on the "path" object. What is the correct way to make this program?

Sorry for the long question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: @Joe C help please

Comment: I think you misunderstand what Stack Overflow is about.  We are a question-and-answer site.  We are not a homework writing service.  You cannot simply dump requirements and code on here, shout "HELP!", and expect us to magically fix it.  **That doesn't happen.**  Not only is it not useful for other readers, it's not useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: there is a [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class in Java API. The [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface contains a little more than the Stack. You can start any implementation, like [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html):

```
Deque<Point> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
stack.push(new Point(2,3));
stack.push(new Point(2,4));
Point p = stack.pop(); // (2, 4)
```

Similarly, there is a [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface with numerous implementations. `ArrayDeque` is one of them:

```
Queue<Point> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
queue.add(new Point(1, 2));
queue.add(new Point(1, 3));
Point p = queue.remove(); // (1, 2)
```

I was using the [`Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class to be used with these tokens.

Bottom line: you can build your maze solver on the top of this classes. So you can focus on the maze solving. The java library will take care of the algorithmic details.